# A sensible budget for each day in Croatia with the Kuna currency?

Tags: budget, money, croatia

I am currently in Slovenia at the moment and will be heading down to Croatia next. This will be my first country in my trip that does not officially use the Euro currency and instead uses the Kuna.

Currently my budget in Euro currency countries is 50 euros a day.

According to XE.com

50.00 EUR   =   375.253 HRK

So to take that arbitrarily would that seem like a sensible budget a day in Croatia or will it be a lot cheaper?

Places I am going to are:

- Zagreb
- Dubrovnik
- Korcula

Comment: The usual questions.  What do you stay in - camping / hostels / hotels? Do you eat out or buy from street stalls or just supermarket shop.  Etc, etc.

Comment: Hostels, I normally get ready meals from super markets unless I want to try something specific

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your activities in Croatia will be similar to what you've been doing in Slovenia, you can expect your daily budget to be similar too.

Out of the way towns in Croatia are a bit cheaper than Slovenia, but prices in places like Zagreb and Dubrovnik are pretty much on par with what you find in Slovenia.

Answer (score 1):

It will not be cheaper.

Croatia is at the top of the tourist season and cheap accommodation is already booked.

This year there are less people then the last year, but living on 50E per day is a bit tight. You can eat for 100kn per day, true, but for finding a decent bad you need a bit of luck.

I think you cannot find anything via Internet on your budget, but there are usually a number of old ladies at the bus and rail stations offering rooms at bargain prices.

Dubrovnik in particular is very expensive.